# Table View gets crashed

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview

I am new in iPhone application development. I am currently working on XML parsing. I am extracting records from an xml file and storing it in an mutable array. I have a table view and i am loading the table view from that mutable array. I get 18 rows in the table view which i found by debugging. The problem is when i scroll down upto 10 rows it moves well but as 10th row appears the app crashes. i get the error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Here is my code where the cell gets loaded. Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        Location *record = [[Location alloc] init];

        record = [[parse locationarr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = record.locationname;

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: show some of your crash log...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your mistake is " return cell" which is written in inside the if condition take it outside also  row title label text set out side condition.like this way..

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    Location *record = [[Location alloc] init];

}
else
{
  // get  record object here  by tag.  
}
record = [[parse locationarr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = record.locationname;

 return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are some misstakes in the code you post, first you only return a cell is the table isn't return a cell for dequeueing

Thus changing you code likewise will solve that problem:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

   Location *record = [[Location alloc] init];
   record = [[parse locationarr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.textLabel.text = record.locationname;

   return cell;
}
```

Also having to `alloc` and `init` a `Location` every time is very costly, it's better to have a `Location` with in the class that you call every time a cell is needed.
Beter yet is to just grab the data for the cell only and not do any lengthy method in the `tableVieew:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Problem Solved. Wrote that code outside the if condition and it worked perfectly. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to write this snippet

```
`record = [[parse locationarr] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = record.locationname;`
```

out of if block.

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: No really since he will still be just returning a cell in the  if statement.

Comment: yes I didn't notice that!! Then he needs return cell also out of block!!